# multiple file uploads with angularJS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to learn angularJS by reading some tutorials, at this stage i'm trying to create a form with multiple upload files (2 separate ones). I thought of using the [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) plugin.

I'm stuck with the below problems,

1) How can i pass values from 2 separate file uploads?

```
<input type="file" name="profile_pic" ng-file-select="onFileSelect">
<input type="file" name="document" ng-file-select="onFileSelect2">
```

2) How do i capture the files separately into a PHP file?

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
 <input type="text" ng-model="age">
 <input type="text" ng-model="title"> 
 <input type="file" name="profile_pic" ng-file-select="onFileSelect">
 <input type="file" name="document" ng-file-select="onFileSelect2">
 <input type='button' ng-click='onFormSubmit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function(file) {

Upload.upload({
    url: 'api/upload-data.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    file: file,
    data: {
        'name': $scope.name,
        'age' : $scope.age ,
        'title' : $scope.title ,


    }
})

  };
}];
```

PHP

```
 //does not show the files
  var_dump($_FILES);
  $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , '/uploads');

  //shows the input texts
  var_dump($_POST)
```

Comment: Multiple files are best uploaded with separate XHR POSTs. If they must be uploaded together in one POST, use content type `multipart/form-data`. Avoid `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because percent-encoding create 3 text bytes for each binary byte.

Comment: @georgeawg i added `multipart/form-data` but in my angular code how can i pass both files and capture them in php?

Comment: Have you seen the example? It's linked in the README. http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/

Comment: yep... but it has only one input which allows to select multiple files. but i need to have 2 (or more) separate input files. eg: one input only for images, one input for documents...

Comment: Create a FormData object and append the data and files to that object. See [MDN Web API Reference - FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Be sure to set `Content-Type: undefined` so that the XHR API has the freedom to include the proper media boundary. When the XHR API sends a FormData object, it sets the `Content-Type` with the proper boundary and encodes the data in base64.

Comment: The other option is to convert the files to DataURLs and send everything as a JSON encoded object.